# Calculate inverse of a function--Library

Tags: python, c, math

Is there any library available to have inverse of a function? To be more specific, given a function `y=f(x)` and domain, is there any library which can output `x=f(y)`? Sadly I cannot use matlab/mathematics in my application, looking for C/Python library..

Comment: But a mathematical function can be arbitrarily complex and some are irreversible (public key encryption). How can this even be possible? You might want to state more specifically what you are trying to achieve and why.

Comment: Yes, but if solves most of function that will be great use to scientist. Assume y=x+2. x=y-2 can help me some circumstances. Depends on need...

Comment: @username_4567 yeah, but that fucntion is easy to inverse. what about y=log(x^sinh(1/x)) (i just invented it). I don't think you can make a function that returns the inverse of ANY function.

Comment: No such library exists, What are your function. Is it possible to encode you function at low level? why do you need ? I mean you should ask whether is it possible..

Comment: if you are talking about user defined functions, simply you have to write the inverse function. 
For library functions no such inverse functions available. And it should not be because each library is for specific purpose and contains specific set of functions.

Answer (score 20):

I am a bit late, but for future readers of the post, I just published a python package that does this precisely. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynverse
There is a detailed description of how to use it and how it does it in the description!

Comment: Wow! Could I have the source code? I need this for a package I'm making.

Answer (score 8):

As has already been mentioned, not all functions are invertible. In some cases imposing additional constraints helps: think about the inverse of `sin(x)`.  This function only is invertible if you look at a domain of x that doesn't have duplicate solutions.

Once you are sure your function, `f(x)=y` has a unique inverse, solve the equation `f(x) - y = 0` for `x`, with a given `y`. The solution gives you the inverse, `g(y)=x` (`f` and `g` are arbitrary letters used to represent the different functions).

In python, look for nonlinear solvers from `scipy.optimize`.